# Автозаполнение массива JS с циклом for

Tags: javascript

Хочу заполнить массив числами от 0 до 10

```
var arr = new Array(10);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  document.writeln( arr.push[i] );
}
```

в результате получается [image: 10 раз undefined]

Comment: `arr.push[i]` что бы это могло значить?

Comment: массиву "arr" присвоить значение "i". Разве не так?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push . Открываем документацию, смотрим, и....

Comment: @НиколайВолков, нет, вы метод `push` использовали не по назначению. Не будем гадать, почему так выглядит ваш код, но вам нужно разобраться, что делает этот метод и как обращаться к элементу массива...

Comment: метод push добавляет элементы в конец массива. Обращаться к элементу массива нужно по индексу. Тогда я создаю пустой массив и этим же методом push заполняю его. результат то же.  var arr = new Array;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  
document.writeln( arr.push[i] );

}

Comment: @НиколайВолков, `new Array(10)` создаст массив длинной 10. Подозреваю, что вы этого не знали и стали применять `push[]`(квадратные скобки???), вместо `push()`. Но ведь этот метод еще вам будет добавлять в конец массива элементы, и ваш код зациклится. Может просто надо `arr[i] = 'Что-то'`?

Comment: проблема была в квадратных скобках. Я этого не заметил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(извиняюсь, получилось многобукаф) Внесу немного ясности...

Если имеем какой-нибудь массив `var arr = ['bubu', 154, 'kuku'];` то его элементы можно достать через номер внутри квадратных скобок:

```
arr[0] == 'bubu'
arr[1] == 154
arr[2] == 'kuku'
```

В массив можно добавлять новые элементы через метод `.push()`

```js
var arr = ['bubu', 154, 'kuku'];
    arr.push('new-bubu');

console.log( arr );
```

Есть еще объекты...

```js
var obj = {'push': '15', 'moo': 159}

console.log( obj.push )
console.log( obj.moo )
```

Но массивы могут храниться и в виде элемента в объекте. Тогда чтобы получить очередной элемент *массива*, который находится в *объекте*, нужно будет записать примерно то же, что писали и вы:

```js
var arr = {
  'push': ['какашка', 2, 555],
  'kuku': ['loo', 15, 145]
}

console.log( arr.push[0] )
console.log( arr.push[1] )
console.log( arr.push[2] )
console.log( arr.push[3] ) // не существует → undefined
```

В примере есть реально существующие элементы массива, поэтому выводятся они, вместо undefined.
Возвращаясь к вашему главному вопросу, несколько вариантов:

```js
var arr = []; 

for (var i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
  document.writeln( arr.push(i) ); 
}
/* Выводит не сами элементы, а количество существующих элементов на каждом круге */
/* Интересная особенность, как оказалось)) Тогда такой код сделал бы то же самое:

for (var i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
  document.writeln( arr.length ); 
} 

*/
```

Или

```js
var arr = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.push(i); /* Сперва добавляем все элементы */
}
document.writeln( arr ); /* Потом сразу выводим весь массив (именно его элементы )*/
```

Или

```js
var arr = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.push(i)
  document.writeln( arr + '<br>' );
}
```

P.s. получается, если через пустой push ничего не добавлять, `arr.length == arr.push()`

А в случае любого добавленного элемента, `arr.length + 1 == arr.push('что-то')`

```js
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

/* Символ == проверяет на равенство. Если равны, возвращает true, если нет - false */

console.log( arr.length )                             // ==5
console.log( arr.length == arr.push() )
console.log( arr.length + 1 == arr.push(1) )          // +1 элем от push()
console.log( arr.length + 1 == arr.push('фвывфы') )   // +1
console.log( arr.push('') )                           // +1
console.log( arr.length )                             // ==8 (это не член)
console.log( arr )

/* При этом .push() срабатывает даже если просто вызван в console.log()
И каждый раз увеличивает массив. */
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)))

Comment: Ещё бы стоило написать, почему `document.writeln( arr.push(i) );` в цикле выводит числа от 1 до 10, а `document.writeln( arr );` после цикла - от 0 до 9. :)

Comment: @Yaant упс, косяк. Спасибо... допишу, как только пойму))

Comment: На всякий случай подсказка: что будет, если там заменить `i` на `0` - `document.writeln( arr.push(0) )`? :)

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.writeln( arr.push[i] );
> ```

```
arr[i] = i;
```